# Как правильно обработать ответ ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Доброго времени суток.

Только начал осваивать технологию *AJAX*.
Совсем сломал голову. Не понимаю как мне правильно обработать ответ от сервера.

Моя функция:

```
function email() {
  var res = ''; // результирующая строка - пока пустая.
  var elem = document.getElementById('mail');
  var str = elem.value; // текст из формы.
  var list = str.split("\n"); // разбивка...
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    str = list[i];

    // пустые строки пропускаем...
    if (str.length < 1) continue;

    // проверка наличия такого емайла в базе...
    request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "email_check.php",
      data: "email=" + str,
      success: function(request, res) {
        if (request == "1") {
          res = res + str + '(есть)' + "\n";
        } else {
          res = res + str + '' + "\n";
        }
      }
    });
  }

  elem.value = res;
}
```

Т.е. у меня есть редактируемое поле на странице - `id='mail';`.
Туда заносятся адреса электронной почты, разделенные знаком переноса строки.
Далее происходит их разбиение на отдельные элементы по символу переноса строки.
Далее - каждый такой отдельный адрес - я проверяю запросом к серверу на уникальность. Если такой уже есть, *email_check.php* - вернет "1", если нет - то "0".
Моя задача - снова получить этот же список *email* - то у тех которые уже есть - нужно дописать `(есть)+\n`, т.е. снова получить такой же список с переносами строк и прописать его обратно в форму в элемент *mail*.

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54858/discussion-on-question-by------ajax-post).

Answer (score 0):

Данную задачу проще решать на сервере так:

1. Получаем дынные из поля
2. Шлем на сервер
3. Разделяем по `\n`, для PHP это можно сделать с [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)
4. Запускаем цикл в нем проверяем и валидные сразу дописываем в переменную
5. Поcле успеха отправляем клиенту (браузеру)
6. Вставляем в поле

В ином случае при большом кол-ве данных вы устраиваете буквально DDOS на свой сервер.

Comment: Да. Все верно. Именно так и решилась задача. Обработкой всей массива на сервере. Спасибо.